# Recommended way to run Room Insert in another thread in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am at the step where in my `Repository` I want to implement running `@Insert` into a new thread, not on UI thread.

I saw that there are a few ways to handle this:

1. Some sample use `AsyncTask` and within `doInBackground` do the `Dao` call
2. The Google sunflower sample uses `runOnIoThread` which is a method that does `IO_EXECUTOR.execute(job)` where `IO_EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`
3. Some seem to use `anko`

`doAsync{
    dao.insert(item)
}`

What is the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should generally have your own Executor wrapped under an interface.

```
public interface Scheduler {
    void runOnThread(Runnable runnable);
}

/**
 * A Scheduler implementation based on ModernAsyncTask with an unbounded task queue.
 **/
public class IoScheduler implements Scheduler {
    private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
    private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

    private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
        private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            return new Thread(r, "IoScheduler #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
        }
    };

    private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

    /**
     * An {@link Executor} that can be used to execute tasks in parallel.
     */
    private static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR =
         new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
                 TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);

    @Override
    public void runOnThread(Runnable runnable) {
        THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.execute(runnable);
    }
}
```

You typically provide these with Dagger:

```
@Singleton
public class IoScheduler implements Scheduler {
    @Inject
    IoScheduler() {}
    ...
}

@Module
public class SchedulerModule {
    public static final String BACKGROUND = "BACKGROUND";

    @Named(BACKGROUND) // you can also use @Qualifier
    @Provides
    Scheduler ioScheduler(IoScheduler ioScheduler) {
        return ioScheduler;
    }
}
```

And then use it elsewhere

```
@Singleton
public class MyService {
    private final Scheduler ioScheduler;

    @Inject
    MyService(@Named(SchedulerModule.BACKGROUND) Scheduler ioScheduler) { // you can use @Qualifier here instead of @Named
        this.ioScheduler = ioScheduler;
    }
    ....
}
```

(though this `ioScheduler` is better for reads: for writes, you might want to consider a separate, single-threaded executor.)

---

So if you read this to its end, it's actually this approach:

> 2.) The Google sunflower sample uses `runOnIoThread` which is a method that does `IO_EXECUTOR.execute(job)` where `IO_EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So you are saying that for write I could use something like `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(DAO.insertItem(item))`

Comment: Heavens no, you'd be creating a new single thread executor for every single insert. Make a singleton instance of the executor and use that globally for writes.

Comment: I am not really familiar yet with Kotlin, still on early learning. Looking at the code sample, https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/utilities/AppExecutors.kt is the `IO_EXECUTOR` created each time `ronOnIoThread` is called? or only one instance?

Comment: Created only once.

Comment: Thank you very much I'll go with this approach